# How do I use a heatmap with vue highcharts?

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I tried using heatmap as the chart type but I am getting error 17. I am using vue-highcharts and wondering how I can fix this proble. I looked online and it seems that I may have to import it and use it. Can anyone show me how to do that because I can't find any documentation on it?

Answer (score 1):

```
import HighCharts from 'highcharts'
import heatmap from 'highcharts/modules/heatmap';

heatmap(HighCharts);
```

These are the import statements for it to work.